# Can this be re-written without "bc"? bc is not installed on most hosts in the environment

Tags: linux, bash, math

I am trying to run this script on multiple hosts but they do not have bc installed.

I read you can use something along the lines of "awk 'BEGIN {print...}' but i am unable to get it working.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

nproc=$(nproc);

load=$(uptime | awk '{print $12}');


load_diff=$(echo "$load - $nproc" | bc)

cores=$(echo "$nproc * .25" | bc)

if (( $(echo "$load_diff > $cores" | bc --mathlib) ));

        then

                top -c -n 2 -b > /tmp/top.txt

fi
```

Comment: `awk` handles floating-point calculations just fine...

Comment: Unrelated, but `nproc` gives you the number of available processors. `load` variable has the average load in last 15 mins. I am not sure if `($load - $nproc)` has any meaning.

Comment: `uptime` on Debian has only 10 blank separated fields... E.g., `10:20:30 up 23:33,  1 user,  load average: 0.52, 0.71, 0.82`

Answer (score 1):

Linux or Unix operating system provides the `bc` and `expr` for doing arithmetic calculations.

So in case `bc` is not installed you can utilize `expr` for calculation.

You can use the below command to perform the same tasks in `expr` :

from :

```
load_diff=$(echo "$load - $nproc" | bc)
```

to :

```
load_diff=$(expr $load - $nproc) or load_diff=`expr $load - $nproc`
```

However, One limitation of `expr` is it doesn't deal with the decimals. For that, you can use below awk command to handle decimals.

```
cores=$(awk 'BEGIN{ print '$nproc' * '.25'}') and load_diff=$(awk 'BEGIN{print '$load' - '$nproc' }')
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk, please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

nproc=$(nproc)
load=$(uptime | awk '{print $12}')

if [[ -n $(awk -v nproc="$nproc" -v load="$load" '
    BEGIN {
        load_diff = load - nproc
        cores = nproc * 0.25
        if (load_diff > cores) print 1
    }') ]]; then
    top -c -n 2 -b > /tmp/top.txt
fi
```

As an alternative, you can perform the calculation by multiplying the parameters by 100:

```
#!/bin/bash

nproc=$(( $(nproc) * 100 ))
load=$(uptime | awk '{print $12 * 100}')

if (( load - nproc > nproc / 4 )); then
    top -c -n 2 -b > /tmp/top.txt
fi
```

Comment: If you don't set `LC_NUMERIC='C'` or `POSIX`, `uptime` may return load averages into floating-point locale dependant display formats that are inappropriate/incompatible with `awk` or `bc`

Comment: If this script runs on linux hosts and has access to /proc/loadavg, then `awk '{print $3 * 100}' </proc/loadavg` would do it without breaking compatibility with locale numeric display format between awk/sed and uptime.

Comment: @LeaGris It may depend on the implementation of `uptime` but Linux `uptime` is not affected by LOCALE or its friends. The snippet in the source code shows it always uses a dot as a decimal point: `seq_printf(m, "%lu.%02lu %lu.%02lu\n",
   (unsigned long) uptime.tv_sec,
   (uptime.tv_nsec / (NSEC_PER_SEC / 100)),
   (unsigned long) idle.tv_sec,
   (idle.tv_nsec / (NSEC_PER_SEC / 100)));`. If you have information about LOCALE dependent `uptime`, please let me know.

Comment: My `uptime` command `uptime de procps-ng 3.3.15` is giving different results depending on `LC_NUMERIC`: `LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8 uptime | awk '{print $12}'` → `0,40`. But `LC_NUMERIC=C uptime | awk '{print $12}'` → `0.40`. The floating-point value format differs on the decimal point: Period `.` or comma`,`. Needless to remind that `awk` or `bc` deals with POSIX formatted floats using a period decimal point. But floats formatted for display most often obey the rule of the `LC_NUMERIC` locale formats. Still if you need to parse floats out of display output, you must set `LC_NUMERIC=POSIX or C`.

Answer (score 1):

The following script

1. Does not uses external processes except `nproc` and `uptime`.
2. Executes `uptime` in a controlled environment, leading to consistent results.
3. Works in every POSIX shell.

```
# multiply the number of processors by 100
nproc=$(( $(nproc) * 100 ))

# get the uptime string in a known format
load=$(LC_NUMERIC=C uptime)

# extract the last field
#    (${parameter##word} remove the longest match of word from the beginning)
load=${load##* }

# join what's before and after the decimal point
load=${load%.*}${load#*.}

# and strip the leading zeros (otherwise load is interpreted in octal)
load=${load##0}

# at this point load is a string like "5" or "47" or "621" or,
# in other words, the load was multiplied by 100

# the math (note: nproc was multiplied by 100 so we can safely divide by 4)
load_difference=$(( $load - $nproc ))
cores=$(( $nproc / 4 ))

# every number has been multiplied by 100 so the comparison is still significant
[ $load_difference -gt $cores ] &&  echo run top
```